# Start a separate program in prolog/swiprolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I want to open firefox or a other browser with prolog code. But how i can realize it.

Specific i need comment for prolog like

open_url_in_Browser X.

where X ist the url.

Answer (score 1):

```
getenv(browser,"firefox"),www_open_url("url name").
```

solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `shell/1` or `shell/2`, or `win_exec/2`, or `win_shell/2`.